# trying to fix this method in my class to, I think maybe try-catch, but the goal is to make the user only be able to enter 1-9

Tags: java

I kept getting an infinite loop so I changed the code and now I get an error. 
I only want the user to be able to enter `1`-`9` (tic-tac-toe game) any advice I'd really appreciate. Here is the method from my class

```
public int move() {  // make it so they can only choose 1-9

    System.out.print("Where do you want to move? ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int move = in.nextInt();
    while(move >=1 || move < 10 )
    {
         System.out.println("that move is invalid must be 1-9");
         break;
    }
     return move;
}
```

and the error is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>       at tictactoe.Board.isValid(Board.java:44)
>       at tictactoe.TicTacToe.main(TicTacToe.java:116)
>       C:\Users\blah\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-
>       snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>       BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)

Comment: Note that the while loop is worthless since it will never loop. Perhaps you want to get the user input from *within* the loop if it is incorrect? Also you do not want to create a bunch of new Scanner objects. Instead create it once in your program and pass it around where needed.

Comment: And if not for the `break;` it would loop infinitely.

Comment: Your error is not coming from the code you posted, it's likely a side-effect of a bad input.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry I forgot to put the error message in and its in there now

Comment: Did you read the error message and stack trace? That has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: @SLaks it probably does. Im assuming that it is returning move with a higher than allowed number, resulting in an array out of bounds exception because you are using the variable this returns in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your logic. Let's try this:

```
public int move() {  // make it so they can only choose 1-9
    System.out.print("Where do you want to move? ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int move = in.nextInt();
    while (move < 1 || move > 9) {
         System.out.println("that move is invalid must be 1-9");
         move = in.nextInt();
    }
    return move;
}
```

Comment: also now that I think about it, how can you make sure that only an integer is entered by the user,. I can't have any letters or special characters. @shmosel

Comment: @Progamminnoob see [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()).

Answer (score 2):

from within the while loop, you want to prompt the user for the move int again using the Scanner class.

```
while(move <= 0 || move >= 10 )
{
   System.out.println("that move is invalid must be 1-9");
   System.out.print("Where do you want to move? ");
   move = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop will loop until the number entered is *invalid*, reverse the conditions in the loop. You will also need to recapture the desired move from the user.

```
while(move < 1 || move >= 10 ) {
         System.out.println("that move is invalid must be 1-9");
         move = in.nextInt();
}
```